# How to create a shortcode out of a php function

Tags: functions, shortcode

How to create a shortcode out of a PHP function?

My code looks like this:

```
function related_links_shortcode() {
      echo do_shortcode("<?php wp_related_posts()?>");
 }
add_shortcode('relatedlinks', 'related_links_shortcode');
```

My code only shows `[relatedlinks]` on my post

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function actually calls another shortcode if that one exists. Instead, it should look like the following:

```
add_shortcode('relatedlinks', 'related_links_shortcode');
function related_links_shortcode() {
    return wp_related_posts();
}
```